# atheros AR9285 compatibility with wpa2 enterprise

Tags: wireless

I have a asus u32u and just install the ubuntu 13.10. I'm new working with linux and need a little help.

My pc has a Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 and I can connect to my Wi-Fi, my problem is in my college, where i can connect via cable but not via Wi-Fi.

My college Wi-Fi:

- security: WPA2 Enterprise
- authentication: Protected EAP (PEAP)
- inner authentication: MSCHAPv2

Any question, just ask. If you need me to put some information about my pc, please leave the respective code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this problem all the time with Linux-based OS's.

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/'name of SSID'
```

The problem is that it's looking for a certificate on the PC to validate the connection.

Go in and find:

```
system-ca-certs=true
```

and change it to:

```
system-ca-certs=false
```

And then try reconnecting. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you up could accept my answer or up vote it, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I accept your answer but I can't vote up because I don't have 15 of reputation, sorry